# Remove rows from dataframe based on cervine string list of values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to remove rows from a dataframe based on multiple conditions, so I defined two lists of the keywords that I want to check before the row is deleted. the condition is when it matches the first list delete unless it contains one of the keywords in the second list.Sample Input and expected Output.
[INPUT AND OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm8BQ.png)

```
 df=pd.read_csv('/content/file.csv',usecols=['date','username','name','tweet'])


List1=['USA','UK','IQ','KW']
List2=['Eygept','Cairo']
df[df["name"].str.contains('|'.join(List1))==False & df["tweet"] != List2]
```

---

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    265         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
--> 266         result = op(x, y)
    267     except TypeError:

7 frames
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas/_libs/ops.pyx in pandas._libs.ops.scalar_binop()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
    290                     f"Cannot perform '{op.__name__}' with a dtyped [{x.dtype}] array "
    291                     f"and scalar of type [{typ}]"
--> 292                 ) from err
    293 
    294     return result.reshape(x.shape)

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [object] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
df[~df["name"].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(List1)) | df["tweet"].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(List2))]
```

### Edit (2021-06-30):

Base on the sample input and output, you can get the result by:

```
df[df["name"].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(List1)) & df["tweet"].astype(str).str.contains('|'.join(List2))]
```

**Result:**

```
        name                            tweet
0    SAM_USA  nice weather in Eygept #WEATHER
4  TOMAS_USA  nice weather in Eygept #WEATHER
6     TOM_KW  nice weather in Eygept #WEATHER
```

Comment: it shows the following @SeaBean -- File "<ipython-input-33-a4498929bfb2>", line 3
    print(df[~df["name"].str.contains('|'.join(List1) & ~df["tweet"].isin(List2), na=False])
                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Eila  Please retry.  Missing one closing bracket.  Corrected.

Comment: @Eila  You added `na=False` for it ?   No need for it.

Comment: @Eila  So, you want to retain the rows when ` df["tweet"]` is in `List2` or not ?  As don't have your sample data, can't be sure of that.  If yes, you probably should use:  `df[~df["name"].str.contains('|'.join(List1)) | df["tweet"].isin(List2)]`

Comment: @Eila  See my last comment above.  That's why I clarified with you in the last comment above.  If yes, use the codes there.

Comment: yes this is exactly what i want is to keep when it finds keywords from the second list, I tried the code and it gives me an error. ----> 3 df[~df["name"].str.contains('|'.join(List1)) | df["tweet"].isin(List2)]

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in apply(self, func, **kwargs)
    344         """
    345         with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
--> 346             result = func(self.values, **kwargs)
    347 
    348         return self._split_op_result(result)

TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: sorry @SeaBean i did not sow your comment when i wrote the previous comment. i tried the code and it gave me the above error.

Comment: @Eila  Is that your `name` column contains some `NaN` or null values, or would it contain some data not of string type ?

Comment: yeah, probably some values in the name column contain not string values like emojis @SeaBean. does"na=False" here works?  or I should just replace those with string values.

Comment: @Eila  You can try to convert the `name` column to strings first by `.astype(str)`.  See my edit above.

Comment: @Eila   No worry, it's just temporary convert for testing, the actual `name` column would not be changed.

Comment: I realized that it still just delete based on the first list unfortunately there is still something missing here.

Comment: @Eila  Note that I can just help you get through the error you showed in the question based on your limited information shown here.  We already go some steps deeper based on what we discussed in comments.  You have to provide some sample data and the expected data output layout in the question for us to further solve the program logical problem yet to be solved.

Comment: @Eila  One last thing we can do before you show some sample data here is that we also change the second part looking at column `tweet` to use `.str.contains()` as well instead of your original logics to check it not equals to `List2`.  Take a try and let me know the result.

Comment: @Eila  Does the latest revised version works for you ?   Let me know if you have tested it.

Comment: Hi@SeaBean thank you for asking and for all the suggested solutions I really appreciate your help. yes, I have tried the last one but still, it does not match the expected output. I have added a sample of what I expect to get after running the code. this is not the original data but something that can let you understand what I want to do.

Comment: @Eila  I have just edited the solution based on your sample input data and expected output data.  See whether this is what you want.  The revised code can successfully get the required output.

Comment: @Eila  I think the result is inconsistent with your description in question.  That's why we can't get your required output based on the description.  If based on your description, we should delete those for `name` in `List1`, then the entry `AHMED_EYG` will still be left in the result (although `tweet` of this row contain `london` which is not in `List2`.

Comment: @Eila  I think it is easier for us to think and say in positive terms (rather than negative terms).   We can think of the conditions to keep the rows (rather than remove the rows).  In this sense, we keep the rows when 2 conditions both match:  1) `name` is in `List1` and also 2) `tweet` is in `List2`  (BOTH conditions).   Seems like this aligns best to the sample input and output.  Anyway, only you can determine whether this is what you want.  Just think about it and let me know.

Comment: The first solution is just perfect because let's say that I don't want to delete people that tweet from Eygpt but delete any other tweets by people that are not from Eygpt except if they are talking about it. deleting them in my case is easier because it is a large data and I already want to get rid of them. Regarding the suggestion meeting both conditions will delete a lot of the data that are not covered by those conditions.  This solved my issue. Thank you so much =)@SeaBean